# How to capitalize the first letter in dict values only

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here is a dictionary

```
dictionary = {'Happy':['SMILE','LAUGH','BEAMING'],
              'Sad':['FROWN','CRY','TEARS'],
              'Indifferent':['NEUTRAL','BLAND', 'MEH']}
```

I am trying to change the values in the entire dictionary such that SMILE becomes Smile, LAUGH becomes Laugh etc.

This is what I'm attempted

```
{str(k).upper():str(v).upper() for k,v in dictionary.values()}
```

But the result of this is capitalizing the keys and does noting to the values.

Comment: well, you need `str.capitalize()` in this case, not `str.upper()`. Also, why do you apply the method also on keys?

Comment: Do you also need to modify the keys? Or was this a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
d = {'Happy':['SMILE','LAUGH','BEAMING'],
              'Sad':['FROWN','CRY','TEARS'],
              'Indifferent':['NEUTRAL','BLAND', 'MEH']}
d = {k:[x.capitalize() for x in v] for k,v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

output

```
{'Happy': ['Smile', 'Laugh', 'Beaming'], 'Sad': ['Frown', 'Cry', 'Tears'], 'Indifferent': ['Neutral', 'Bland', 'Meh']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
{k.upper():[s.capitalize() for s in v]
 for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

output:

```
{'HAPPY': ['Smile', 'Laugh', 'Beaming'],
 'SAD': ['Frown', 'Cry', 'Tears'],
 'INDIFFERENT': ['Neutral', 'Bland', 'Meh']}
```

*NB. this is also changing the key to capitals, I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. If not use `k` or `k.capitalize()`*

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```py
result = {k: [emotion[0].upper() + emotion[1:].lower() for emotion in v] for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Then `result` is

{'Happy': ['Smile', 'Laugh', 'Beaming'], 'Sad': ['Frown', 'Cry',
'Tears'], 'Indifferent': ['Neutral', 'Bland', 'Meh']}